# Change page layout of existing web part page

Tags: 2013, web-part-page

Is there a built in way to change between preset page layouts in an existing web part page?  Currently I end up deleting the page and creating a new one with the appropriate layout.  I feel like there should be a way to do this.

EDIT:

Here's what I am seeing for each type of page.

Article page:

[image]

Wiki page:

[image]

Web part page:

[image]

Comment: Usually in the ribbon there is the option to switch the page layout, it might be dependent on the publishing features being active, not 100% certain about that.

Comment: I know you can do this with a wiki page whenever you need in the ribbon.  I do not see it available with a web part page however.  Publishing features are enabled as well.  Although this page lives in the Site Pages library rather than the Pages library that is created when publishing is turned on.

Comment: That could be the issue with it being in the Site Pages, I know it is available, I've used it in the past.

Comment: Checked the Pages library, there is an option to select a Page, Article Page, or Welcome Page.  The article page gives preset layouts but they aren't true web part pages that you would get in the Site Pages library.  I added the Web Part Page content type and created a page in the Pages library.  Didn't see it in the ribbon there either.

Comment: it would be in the ribbon on the page itself, not in the library. So pages/somepage.aspx, that ribbon, when in edit mode.

Comment: Right, I created a web part page in the Pages library, edited the page, and checked there.  Updated question with images of what I'm seeing for each type of page.

Comment: Why do you insist to use Web Part page, you can create an Article Page and add Web Parts to it? It will be easy to switch Page Layouts and/or create custom Page Layouts too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate "**SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure**" site collection feature under:
**Site Settings>Site Collection Administration(top level)>Site Collection Features**

After that go to site or sub site **Site Settings>Site Actions>Manage Site Features** 
and activate "**SharePoint Server Publishing**"

Publishing pages are stored under **Pages** library(under Site Contents). You can set page layouts on publishing pages not on web part pages. Web part pages are stored under **Site Pages**. Edit a page under **Pages** library or create a new one. You will be able to change the page layouts on that page.